# Http POST request from Angular 6 app using Sendgrid and NodeJs Google Cloud Function - Error 405

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to see an Email using Sendgrid from an Angular 6 application using the minimum payload. Using a Google Cloud Function when I post the request I get error 405 from the browser:

> https://MyCloudFunctions/httpEmail 405
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://MyCloudFunctions/httpEmail' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The Cloud Function Log shows:

> Error: Only POST requests are accepted at Promise.resolve.then (/user_code/index.js:26:23) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

**Cloud Function code**

```
const sendgrid = require('sendgrid');
const client = sendgrid("MyAPI_KEY");

function parseBody(body) {
  var helper = sendgrid.mail;
  var fromEmail = new helper.Email(body.from);
  var toEmail = new helper.Email(body.to);
  var subject = body.subject;
  var content = new helper.Content('text/html', body.content);
  var mail = new helper.Mail(fromEmail, subject, toEmail, content);
  return  mail.toJSON();
}

exports.sendgridEmail = (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        const error = new Error('Only POST requests are accepted');
        error.code = 405;
        throw error;
      }

      // Build the SendGrid request to send email
      const request = client.emptyRequest({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/v3/mail/send',
        body: getPayload(req.body),
      });

      // Make the request to SendGrid's API
      console.log(`Sending email to: ${req.body.to}`);
      return client.API(request);
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode >= 400) {
        const error = Error(response.body);
        error.code = response.statusCode;
        throw error;
      }

      console.log(`Email sent to: ${req.body.to}`);

      // Forward the response back to the requester
      res.status(response.statusCode);
      if (response.headers['content-type']) {
        res.set('content-type', response.headers['content-type']);
      }
      if (response.headers['content-length']) {
        res.set('content-length', response.headers['content-length']);
      }
      if (response.body) {
        res.send(response.body);
      } else {
        res.end();
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      const code =
        err.code || (err.response ? err.response.statusCode : 500) || 500;
      res.status(code).send(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
}
```

** Update: simplified TS file **
**Angular TS File**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  //constructor(private sendgridService: SendgridService){}
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  ngOnInit() { }

  sendEmail() {

    let url = `https://us-central1-probalance-214005.cloudfunctions.net/httpEmail?sg_key=MY_API_KEY`
    let body = {
      "personalizations": [
        {
          "to": [
            {
              "email": "myemail@example.com",
              "name": "Postman"
            }
          ],
          "subject": "Success"
        }
      ],
      "from": {
        "email": "myemail2@example.com",
        "name": "Angular App"
      },
      "reply_to": {
        "email": "myemail@example.com",
        "name": "Test"
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "text/plain",
          "value": "Request Successful 001!"
        }
      ]
    };

    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };
    console.log("Payload:")
    console.log(url)
    console.log(body);
    console.log(httpOptions.headers)

    return this._http.post(url, body, httpOptions)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }
}
```

**Angular HTML File**

`<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary (click)="sendEmail()">Sendgrid </button>`

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header. So, it should be set in the server code, not in the client code written in Angular.
- Since you have set Content-Type, the browser sends an OPTIONS request instead of POST. So, make sure OPTIONS request type is enabled and Content-Type is allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers in the server.

You can understand more about CORS issue here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I added the following code to my cloud function request:
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
now I'm still getting a CORS error but now its 400. Is there some else the call needs from the server.

Comment: I also removed the httpOptions from my client.

Comment: 400 is for Bad request. If you're using Chrome, seeing the Network tab in the Developer console gives you details about the requests and responses. Please check if the request is going as OPTIONS or POST and what response is sent from the server

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. Turns out I temporarily change my url to make a GitHub commit is why I was getting a 400. So my url back to the cloud function trigger. now I'm getting 405 again. The message I'm getting on the browser is "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error ". Server side I'm still getting the same error in logs.

Comment: Have you changed this line to allow OPTIONS request? `if (req.method !== 'POST')`